# Generate a conga report with account and 3 custom objects

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, merge-field, conga

I have 2 parent objects - Account and SP. Account has one child object - Actls and SP has another child object - Trgt. 
I want to fetch data from 2 child objects - Acts and Trgt in same table set.
I tried creating joined report however Conga doesn't support it.
Not sure how I achieve this. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question - I'm the Product Marketing Specialist at Conga.

Although Conga Composer doesn't support joined reports, it supports the use of up to 50 unique Salesforce Reports or SOQL Queries as data sets in a single merge process.  It sounds like you can't include both of your target objects in a non-joined report, so I'd recommend using 2 separate reports that span the respective **Account->Acts** and **SP->Trgt** relationships and then including both reports in your Conga Composer button URL.  The parameter syntax will look a little something like:

&ReportID=[Your1stAliasGoesHere]00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx,[Your2ndAliasGoesHere]00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx

This article in our KnowledgeBase explains how to add reports to a button URL: http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=910

I hope this helps, but please feel free to contact our support team at any time to get hands-on assistance with your solution: http://www.congasphere.com/live-support.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert.
However I want to fetch the data of 2 objects in same tableset. According to your condition, I will get 2 alias name and I cant write both alias name in one tableset. That is the issue I am facing. I want to display the data from 2 objects in same row.

Comment: You're welcome @Prateek, thanks for clarifying.  I'm afraid that unless your two objects share some sort of relationship in Salesforce, Conga Composer won't be able to include data from both in the same row of a table in your output file.  That said, have you considered creating a junction object between the **Act** and **Trgt** objects?  That would definitely allow you to gather Act and Trgt records in the same dataset (custom report type or SOQL query, either one ought to work).